# Big O notation and measuring time according to it

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Suppose we have an algorithm that is of order O(2^n). Furthermore, suppose we multiplied the input size n by 2 so now we have an input of size 2n. How is the time affected? Do we look at the problem as if the original time was 2^n and now it became 2^(2n) so the answer would be that the new time is the power of 2 of the previous time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding here about how Big-O relates to execution time.

Consider the following formulas which define execution time:

`f1(n) = 2^n + 5000n^2 + 12300`

`f2(n) = (500 * 2^n) + 6`

`f3(n) = 500n^2 + 25000n + 456000`

`f4(n) = 400000000`

Each of these functions are `O(2^n)`; that is, they can each be shown to be less than `M * 2^n` for an arbitrary `M` and starting `n0` value.  But obviously, the change in execution time you notice for doubling the size from `n1` to `2 * n1` will vary wildly between them (not at all in the case of `f4(n)`).  You **cannot** use Big-O analysis to determine effects on execution time.  It only defines an upper boundary on the execution time (which is not even guaranteed to be the minimum form of the upper bound).

Some related academia below:

---

There are three notable bounding functions in this category:

> `O(f(n))`: Big-O     - This defines a upper-bound.
>
> `Ω(f(n))`: Big-Omega - This defines a lower-bound.
>
> `Θ(f(n))`: Big-Theta - This defines a tight-bound.

A given time function `f(n)` is `Θ(g(n))` only if it is also `Ω(g(n))` and `O(g(n))` (that is, both upper and lower bounded).

You are dealing with Big-O, which is the usual "entry point" to the discussion; we will neglect the other two entirely.

Consider the definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

> Let f and g be two functions defined on some subset of the real numbers. One writes:
>
> `f(x)=O(g(x))` as x tends to infinity
>
> if and only if there is a positive constant M such that for all sufficiently large values of x, the absolute value of f(x) is at most M multiplied by the absolute value of g(x). That is, f(x) = O(g(x)) if and only if there exists a positive real number M and a real number x0 such that
>
> `|f(x)| <= M|g(x)|` for all x > x0

Going from here, assume we have `f1(n) = 2^n`.  If we were to compare that to `f2(n) = 2^(2n) = 4^n`, how would `f1(n)` and `f2(n)` relate to each other in Big-O terms?

Is `2^n <= M * 4^n` for some arbitrary `M` and `n0` value?  Of course!  Using `M = 1` and `n0 = 1`, it is true.  Thus, `2^n` **is** upper-bounded by `O(4^n)`.

Is `4^n <= M * 2^n` for some arbitrary `M` and `n0` value?  This is where you run into problems... for no constant value of  `M` can you make `2^n` grow faster than `4^n` as `n` gets arbitrarily large. Thus, `4^n` **is not** upper-bounded by `O(2^n)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question was on the same algorithm that is of order O(2^n) (so not f1(n) and f2(n) but only f1(n)) and I asked what would happen if for example the time needed for this algorithm to run an  input of size 2n if it runs on an input of size n in t sec. So is the time needed for the new input t^2?

Comment: The time needed cannot be defined by Big-O analysis; something that is `O(2^n)` can have several other terms that affect execution time outside of the exponential term (and is not even guaranteed to have an exponential term).  Look at `f4(n)` (which is `O(2^n)`); how would `f4(n)` change if you doubled from `n=4` to `n=8`?  The change would be 0.  Do the same analysis for `f2(n)`, and the change would be 120,000.  Two very different answers despite both being `O(2^n); Big-O analysis tells you **absolutely nothing** about how changes in n affects execution time.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped!  If the answer helped you, I'd appreciate it if you could accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Big 0 is not for telling you the actual running time, just how the running time is affected by the size of input. If you double the size of input the complexity is still O(2^n), n is just bigger.

```
number of elements(n)    units of work
        1                      1
        2                      4
        3                      8
        4                      16
        5                      32
        ...                    ...
        10                     1024
        20                     1048576
```

Comment: I meant how is the running time is affected, does it double triple...?

Comment: Much worse than doubling or tripling, it may grow at a factor of 2^n

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy Important to note that it also may not grow at all.  Big-O does not specify a tight boundary; only that the function is upper-bounded by it.  IE: `f(n) = 100` would be `O(2^n)` (it is also `O(1)`).

Answer (score -2):

*See comments for further explanations, but **indeed**, this is just an example I came up with to help you grasp Big-O concept. That is **not** the actual algorithmic meaning.*

Suppose you have an array, `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

- An example of a `O(1)` operation would be directly access an index, such as `arr[0]` or `arr[2]`.
- An example of a `O(n)` operation would be a loop that could iterate through all your array, such as `for elem in arr:`.

`n` would be the size of your array. If your array is twice as big as the original array, `n` would also be twice as big. That's how **variables** work.

See [Big-O Cheat Sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) for complementary informations.

Comment: That is not what `O(1)`, `O(n)`, or `O(2n)` "mean".

Comment: I am adding context to my answer. And since he asks this question, one could believe OP doesn't get the meaning of Big-O notation.

Comment: @OlafSzmidt Why should this be a joke ? Please elaborate and teach/correct me if wrong statements there are, instead of throwing random taunt. :)

Comment: Big O means  "not worse than", little o means "not betther than", θ means "not worse and not better than". But keep in mind that time complexity is about order of magnitude.

Comment: I know that Big-O means the worse-case scenario, and that little-O means the best-case. But, in my example, I explicitly said `Suppose you have` in the problem declaration, and `O(...) **would mean**`. That's called an analogy if I'm correct, and it greatly helps grasping more abstract concepts. :)

Comment: But it's not what it would mean.  They are examples, not meaning.  The question asker could come away from looking at this answer thinking that `O(1)` means to access an index of an array when dealing with arrays (which is, of course, not correct).

Comment: You're right that would be confusing, I'll just specify this, and keep the downvotes.